# Python: track the percentage of the job processed

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, lambda

I have the following code which runs for a long time:

```
my_df['result'] = my_df.apply(lambda x: my_fun(x), axis = 1)
```

`my_df` is a pandas data frame and I have millions of rows. Is there a way to find out what percentage of job have been finished? e.g. put a print statement in my_fun or somewhere? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're doing something that would disconnect your process from `sys.stdout` (rare but plausible) or `sys.stderr` (significantly rarer but still technically not impossible), your idea of just putting a print statement in `my_fun` should work just fine.

Of course, you won't be able to do that to log progress mid-expression in `my_fun`, such as if `my_fun` calls some `other_fun` that takes a very long time. In that case, you'd have to put the print in `other_fun`. For example, if you're doing something to every row separately, you could put a print somewhere in the relevant loop, saying how many rows have been completed, fairly easily. Just keep count, and print the number (possibly to `sys.stderr` or a logger, instead of `sys.stdout`, if you're using `sys.stdout` for something else) every time it hits a multiple of, say, 1000 (or 10,000, or 100,000 - pick a number that works for your use) . Don't print every row - it'll blur past too fast to actually read, if a single row is quick to handle, and you might end up spending enough time on printing that it actually slows down the processing meaningfully.

If you're doing one single operation that needs to take all the data into account, without a loop... you could still do progress reports within the function, but there's no real way to get a "number of rows completed" statistic and it's probably going to be more difficult to get an accurate percentage.

Comment: can u provide an example how to print the percentage of the progress in my_fun()? Since it is called by lambda, I don't know how it tracks the entire job progress...

Comment: Not more specifically knowing what `my_fun` actually is. Just... add a print statement at whatever point in the function you want it to print something. Maybe give the function an attribute to keep count, so as to not print on every repetition.